# React native Build failed

Tags: react-native, build

I create react-native project on my laptop and it builds successfully.

But with the same project I try to run it on my desktop pc but it gives an error build failed.

Why?

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

Comment: Can you please include the build error?

Comment: it's completely execute?

Comment: i added screeshots

Comment: I think you should open another terminal then go to the path of your project and run "yarn start" then try to do "react-native run-android" in your current terminal. let me know the result please.

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me when I tried to compile with Windows OS while the main project was built in Ubuntu and there was a dot "." in one of my libraries folder names which is not permitted in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have not gone into the details of this error. In my case, it will compile if the 'unable to delete directory' is deleted manually.